# Connect to the cloud directly to the database or through a service?

Tags: database, architecture, azure, cloud

it might be a simple question but as I couldn't find the best answer on google I would like to know your thoghts.

I'm thinking of changing a software I've made in WPF accessing its data from a local server to a cloud server (maybe Azure).

What's the best way, connect directly to the database or access through a service in the clould (that would have to be developed by me I guess).

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would guard against directly accessing a database hosted in the cloud via a client application. You'll be exposing your database endpoint through the public internet providing a significant attack vector.

By using a service, you can limit that attack vector. The service itself is also 'exposed' but can be locked down (typically more effectively/easily) with authentication/authorization protocols like OAuth, AD, etc. AND the service itself would expose only the operations necessary for the client application, versus access to the complete database schema (should someone crack the password when the database is on the open internet).

You didn't mention if you were planning to use Windows Azure SQL Azure or your own database in IaaS. You can, of course, implement your own security via firewall, etc. on VMs hosted in Windows Azure, but that's another infrastructure task you'll need to accommodate, and if your client IPs change, etc., then managing that is not insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question would be the same whether you'd be on Azure or not.

A service adds an abstraction layer between the application and the database, which may help with maintenance in the long term, but it does have a cost associated with it (in terms of initial effort) and some potentially performance penalties (although this does not have to be significant) so in the end you'll have to weight it according to the application.

I really do not think there's a one-size-fits-all answer to this.